# Подсчет звуковых ударов

Tags: java, android

Просьба направить в нужном направлении. Стоит задача перехватить звуковые удары и сделать их подсчет. Что я имею ввиду - есть зонд, который забивается молотом в грунт, смысл таков - смартфон находится рядом с этим процессом и фиксирует  количество ударов молота по зонду.

Answer (score 1):

Задача вообще не из простых.
Для начала ознакомься с классом **MediaRecorder** - данный класс позволит записывать звук через микрофон.
Далее, **почитай о работе с файлами** [ссылка](http://devcolibri.com/1141). Как научишься находить нужные файлы на устройстве и вести работу с ними тебе придется потратить не мало времени на следующий шаг. Я предполагаю, тебе нужно будет **конвертировать файл в wave** и вести работу уже с ним. От туда ты сможешь читать байты и многое делать, но это очень сложно. Думаю всё.

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации подобной задачи необходимо проводить спектральный анализ аудиопотока и выявлять пики - те самые удары. Так что стоит поискать в направлении использования какой-нибудь библиотеки для выполнения спектрального анализа. И лучше искать в англоязычных источниках.

Думаю, если вопрос ещё актуален, то это может поспособствовать в решении поставленной задачи:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293953/how-to-develop-a-spectrum-analyser-from-a-realtime-audio

https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples

Наткнулся на данный вопрос только лишь потому, что перед самим стоит идентичная задача %)

UPD:
В принципе, чем это не распознавание речи? https://habrahabr.ru/post/237589/